# No Content-Disposition header in response from mechanize

Tags: python, http-headers, mechanize, google-ads-api

I have to download the csv file from AdWords Billing page during the Celery task. And I have no idea what's wrong with my implementation, so need your help.

Log in:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin')
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['Email'] = g_email
browser['Passwd'] = g_password
browser.submit()

browser.set_handle_robots(False)
billing_resp = browser.open('https://adwords.google.com/')
```

It's OK, I'm on the billing page now. Next, I've parsed the result page for token and ids, analyzed request headers and action url in Chrome debugger and now I want to make POST request and receive my csv file. Response headers (in Chrome) are:

```
content-disposition:attachment; filename="myclientcenter.csv.gz"
content-length:307479
content-type:application/x-gzip; charset=UTF-8
```

With mechanize:

```
data = {
    '__u': effectiveUserId,
    '__c': customerId,
    'token': token,
}

browser.addheaders = [
    ('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
    ('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    ("accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"),
    ('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0"),
    ('referer', "https://adwords.google.com/mcm/Mcm?__u=8183865359&__c=3069937889"),
    ('origin', "https://adwords.google.com"),
]

browser.set_handle_refresh(True)
browser.set_debug_responses(True)
browser.set_debug_redirects(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.set_debug_http(True)
browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)

response = browser.open(
    'https://adwords.google.com/mcm/file/ClientSummary/',
    data='&'.join(['='.join(pair) for pair in data.items()]),
)
```

BUT! The Content-Length header is 0 and no Content-Disposition in this response. Why? And what can I do to make it work?

Had a try to use Requests, but could not even pass the login stage...

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer on my own question now (thanks for my team lead).

The main mistake is in this incorrect request data:

```
data = {
    '__u': effectiveUserId,
    '__c': customerId,
    'token': token,
}
```

Let's try again, with proper solution.

```
# Open Google login page and log in.
browser = mechanize.Browser()
try:
    browser.open('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin')
    browser.select_form(nr=0)
    browser['Email'] = 'email@adwords.login'
    browser['Passwd'] = 'password'
    browser.submit()
except HTTPError:
    raise AdWordsException("Can't find the Google login form")
```

We are logged in now and can go deeper.

```
try:
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    billing_resp = browser.open('https://adwords.google.com/')
except HTTPError:
    raise AdWordsException("Can't open AdWords dashboard page")

# Welcome to the AdWords billing dashboard. We can get 
# session-unique token from this page for the further POST-request
token_re = re.search(r"token:\'(.{41})\'", billing_resp.read())
if token_re is None:
    raise AdWordsException("Can't parse the token")

# It's time for some magic now. We have to construct proper mcsSelector
# serialized data structure. This is GWT-RPC wire protocol hell.
# Paste your specific version from web debugger.
MCS_TEMPLATE = (
    "7|0|49|https://adwords.google.com/mcm/gwt/|18FBB090A5C26E56AC16C9DF0689E720|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.selector.Selector/1054041135|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.date.DateRange/1118087507|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.date.Date/373224763|"
    "java.util.ArrayList/4159755760|java.lang.String/2004016611|ClientName|"
    "ExternalCustomerId|PrimaryUserLogin|PrimaryCompanyName|IsManager|"
    "SalesChannel|Tier|AccountSettingTypes|Labels|Alerts|CostWithCurrency|"
    "CostUsd|Clicks|Impressions|Ctr|Conversions|ConversionRate|SearchCtr|"
    "ContentCtr|BudgetAmount|BudgetStartDate|BudgetEndDate|BudgetPercentSpent|"
    "BudgetType|RemainingBudget|ClientDateTimeZoneId|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.selector.OrderBy/524388450|"
    "SearchableData|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.sorting.SortOrder/2037387810|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.pagination.Paging/363399854|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.selector.Predicate/451365360|"
    "SeedObfuscatedCustomerId|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.selector.Predicate$Operator/2293561107|"
    "java.util.Arrays$ArrayList/2507071751|[Ljava.lang.String;/2600011424|"
    "3069937889|ExcludeSeeds|true|ClientTraversal|DIRECT|"
    "com.google.ads.api.services.common.selector.Summary/3224078220|included|1|"
    "2|3|4|5|"
    "{report_date}|5|{report_date}"  # take a note of this
    "|6|26|7|8|7|9|7|10|7|11|7|12|7|13|7|14|7|15|7|16|7|17|7|18|7|19|7|20|7|21|"
    "7|22|7|23|7|24|7|25|7|26|7|27|7|28|7|29|7|30|7|31|7|32|7|33|6|0|0|0|6|2|34|"
    "35|36|0|34|9|-35|37|100|0|6|0|6|3|38|39|40|2|41|42|1|43|38|44|40|0|41|42|1|"
    "45|38|46|-45|41|42|1|47|0|0|6|0|6|1|48|6|0|49|6|0|0|"
)

# To take stats for today
report_date = datetime.date.today()
mcs_selector = MCS_TEMPLATE.format(
    report_date='%s|%s|%s' % (
        report_date.day,
        report_date.month,
        report_date.year
    ),
)
data = urllib.urlencode({
    'token': token_re.group(1),
    'mcsSelector': mcs_selector,
})

# And... it finally works! Token and proper mcsSelector is all we need. 
# POST-request with this data returns zipped csv file for us with
# current balance state and another info that's not available via AdWords API
zipped_csv = browser.open(
    'https://adwords.google.com/mcm/file/ClientSummary', 
    data=data
)
# Unpack it and use as you wish.
with gzip.GzipFile(mode='r', fileobj=zipped_csv) as csv_io:
    try:
        csv = StringIO.StringIO(csv_io.read())
    except IOError:
        raise AdWordsException("Can't get CSV file from response")
    finally:
        browser.close()
```